# How to call Parametarized .jar file from S3 to serverless template

Tags: aws-codepipeline, aws-cloudformation-custom-resource

I am working on AWS severless JAVA Ci/Cd. I have setup Codepipeline, Every commit build will trigger and complile the source code, store the artifacts in to s3 bucket. Now how to call lastest jar file from S3 to cloud formation template using Parameterized. 
Finally every commit build will trigger and deploy automatically. 
Please help on this.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Add another stage to your Pipeline with CloudFormation action. This action takes some config properties like stack name and template. Among them is a properties called 'Parameter overrides' [1], this configuration property allows you to send parameters to the CloudFormation template at runtime so you can send the name of the S3 file as a parameter to CloudFormation. You can use Variables [2] feature to pass the S3 file name from previous action to the CloudFormation action.

Ref:

[1] https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/continuous-delivery-codepipeline-action-reference.html#w2ab1c13c14b7

[2] https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codepipeline/latest/userguide/reference-variables.html